# Yahoo OAuth not redirecting to callback uri

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I am making call for yahoo oauth

```
public async Task<ActionResult> YahooCalendar()
    {
        var url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost.com/Event/getToken&response_type=code&language=en-us";
        return Redirect(url);
    }
```

I have set the callback domain as localhost.com

[But it is giving me this error][1]

how should i make the redirect uri to callback on another function in my controller?

Comment: Don't you have to put the port? in your `localhost` url?

Comment: @balexandre when i put the port number it gives an error about wrong redirect uri

Comment: I guess redirectURL's can't have port numbers, for your example to work, you need to setup port 80 instead the one Visual Studio gives you... several posts in here about how to change that...

Comment: @charlietfl yes it got accepted and it works fine. i get the authorization code too but it doesn't redirect to the function i want.

Comment: @balexandre can you please give link to one that works alright?

Comment: just shut down your IIS if you have it (at it takes port 80 by default), then in your project: Project properties > Web > select Specific Port and fill in `80`. If you get an error that is already in use, that's because you didn't shut down IIS.

Comment: @balexandre it is still not working with http://localhost:80/Event/getToken . it gives a 404 not found error.

Comment: you can't add `:80` that's the default port! No need to specify. Plus, you need to see if that link you are passing actually works

Comment: @balexandre the link works with http://localhost:51419/Event/getToken, but when I pass it as a redirect uri it gives a redirect mismatch error. the domain is just localhost.com.

Comment: @balexandre i removed the port number but the issue is now localhost.com does not match with localhost/Event/getToken . to make it match i have to keep the redirect url as localhost.com/Event/getToken which again says localhost is taking to long to respond

Comment: if the issue is the domain, then get a domain service (I use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)) so you can match a domain name to your localhost in any port ... free version gives you a new domain per start.